# Using date-fns with Firestore Server Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to use https://date-fns.org/ to format my Firestore Server Timestamps in React Native

I have this example function from the documentation

`formatDistance(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date(), { addSuffix: true })`

I am assuming the formatDistance takes two parameters. The date in which in which I am calculating and also the current date. (to calculate the distance)

However, when using:

```
formatDistance(subDays(new Date(), item.created_at.toDate()), new Date(), { addSuffix: true, })
```

(item.created_at) - is my timestamp.

I am getting the error:

```
Invalid time value
```

Answer (score 0):

For subDays based on this [documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/subDays), the required arguments are date (the date to be changed) and amount (amount of days to be subtracted to the 1st argument). The subDays is expecting a number for 2nd argument, but you provided it with a date. You can use formatDistance without subDays.

In your use case, this should be sufficient.

```
formatDistance(new Date(item.created_at.toDate()), new Date(), { addSuffix: true, })
```

This should work as long as the formatting of item.created is correct. Here's the [documentation for formatDistance](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/formatDistance).